# Concurrent modification issue in map

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I am using a **concurrent hashmap** of structure

```
Map<Set<Date>, Map<String, Object>> SampleMap
```

The Map used inside the given map (`Map<String, Object>`) is also a concurrent hashmap, 
but set is a only `TreeSet` type.

Still I get concurrent Modification exception when I add following line in logs,

```
logger.debug("sampleMap.keySet() + ". Size is " + sampleMap.keySet().size()");
```

and also in some other parts of same class dealing with this map.

This map is extensively used in Batch process by multiple threads to put and remove values in map and java version used is 1.5.

I think the exception is due to Treeset and also i find there is no similar implementation of concurrent handling collection for type Set.

It would be great if any one confirm whether my thinking over given issue is correct and also please suggest solution for this problem?

Comment: To start with, using a mutable object as a key for the map is a bad idea (undefined behaviour)..

Comment: I think it's the call to Set.size() that does it, and TreeSet is pretty stateful but not thread safe. Try Collections.synchronizedSet(Set<T>) on your set before placing it as a key in the Map just to see if this is the issue.

Comment: I agree with assylias, you should REALLY consider a different key than `Set`

Comment: That said, Guava has a `Table` construct for Map of Maps. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html

Comment: Be careful, when you call sampleMap.keySet() you are not getting your TreeSet of dates, but a set containing ALL TreeSet of dates... What is the point of calling 'size()' on the keySet (which is for sure not thread safe) instead of on the map directly ??? Here is your concurrent issue I guess...

Comment: That line you are adding doesn't compile. Stack trace would be helpful. I assume (sort of) that you aren't modifying sets whilst they are used as keys.

Comment: In my class the set is modified by adding and removing date. This functionality cant be changed for now. so is there any other option to overcome this issue

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to be able to "modify" the key, you need to follow this pattern

```
// lock the collection
Map<String, Object> values = map.remove(key);
key = new TreeSet<String>(key);
// modify copy of key
map.put(key, values);
// unlock the collection.
```

As you are performing an operation which ConcurrentMap does not support, you have to use your own locking.  You can use a plain HashMap or LinkedHashMap with synchronized or ReentrantReadWriteLock.

---

You can create a Concurrent set using

```
// Added in Java 1.6
Set<String> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>());
// or to be sorted
Set<String> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Boolean>());
```

However, you can't change the contents of a key so what you should be using is

```
Set<String> key = Collections.unmodifiableSet(treeSet);
// or to be sure its not modified
Set<String> key = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new TreeSet<String>(treeSet));
```

---

A simple example of why you cannot change a key after using it in a Map.

```
Set<String> key1 = new TreeSet<String>();
Map<Set<String>, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Set<String>, Boolean>();
map.put(key1, true);
System.out.println("Is the map ok? "+map.containsKey(key1));
key1.add("hello");
System.out.println("Is the map ok? "+map.containsKey(key1));
```

prints

```
Is the map ok? true
Is the map ok? false
```

The common behaviour is that it can no longer see the key in the map.  This is because the map places the key into a bucket based on its hashCode. If the hashCode changes, it can be in the wrong bucket so when it looks for it, it can't find it.

Comment: +1 for unmodifiableSet - not sure the second version is required though.

Comment: If a reference to the original set is being retained, you would need to take a copy. Is unlikely the second version is needed, but you shouldn't be changing a key either so perhaps you can't be too paranoid. ;)

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for you suggestion. but i am using Java Version 1.5 and i am not supposed to increment java version. can you say equivalent steps using java 5 ?

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableSet is in Java 5.0. This is likely to be the best option in any case.

Comment: But in my class the set is modified by adding and removing date. This functionality cant be changed for now. so is there any other option to overcome this issue.

Comment: If you change a key after it has been added in any important way, you have corrupted the Map. I assume this is not a requirement. ;) Can you explain why you believe you need to do this?

Comment: Added an example of why you can't change a key after it has been added to a Map.

Comment: This map is maintained in cache and the maximum size of set is 15. so the set in map is modified whenever latest date is found removing the old date of existing 15 dates. And also the map will always have only one key value pair ie (A key set containing 15 dates and map corresponding to that set.)

Comment: peter, the set is not actually modified. when a latest date is found the existing date set key and corresponding value is removed from map and new set containing latest 15 dates is added to map along with map value(map<string,object>). sorry if i had confused you in my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks peter, the same is done but locking is missed here. i will implement locking around the set when modifying it.